# Cauchy problem for Hamilton-Jacobi equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, action

In [Arnol'd V.I, "Mathematical methods of classical mechanics" p.257](https://books.google.it/books/content?id=5OQlBQAAQBAJ&hl=it&pg=PA257&img=1&zoom=3&sig=ACfU3U34mzmsGfnGRtByqMq9Bn_g9PQGcA&w=1280), I was asked to find a solution for the Cauchy problem

$$H=\frac{p^2}{2},\ \ \ S_0=\frac{q^2}{2}$$

of the Hamilton-Jacobi equation

$$S(A)=S_0(q_0)+\int^A_{q_0,t_0} L(q,\dot q,t)dt$$

Where $S(A)$ is the action functional, $H$ is the hamiltonian function of the system, $L$ its lagrangian, and $p,q$ is the usual couple con conjugated variables.

Someone could help?